# Problema al abrir Api Whatsapp (enviar mensaje) con Chrome android

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

La pagina web después de que el usuario llena un formulario recarga la misma pagina enviando un metodo post (del formulario) el cual detecta la pagina y al estar con contenido envia al usuario por medio de javascript al enlace de la api whatsapp para enviar mensajes.

En chrome desde android funciono solamente una vez, después me envía a la siguiente pagina

[image: pagina al tratar de enviar mensaje por medio de la api]

y al hacer clic en enviar me lleva a la pagina de whatsapp

[image: la pagina a la cual me lleva]

el código que tengo para este proceso es el siguiente

```
$url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=---minumero---&text=Hola,%20Mi%20nombre%20es%20$name%20estoy%20interesado(a)%20en%20*****";

echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location.href = '$url';</script>";
```

Esto se carga en la parte de php del archivo index.php antes del html, ya probé con `open('$url');` también probé cambiando la url de la api por `https://wa.me/` según describe la documentación en el [FAQ de whatsapp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/es/android/26000030/).

Con otros navegadores móviles como Opera, Mozilla he incluso el navegador nativo funciona perfectamente las veces que haga el proceso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me pasaba lo mismo, cambié la url por whatsapp://send?text=Tu mensaje!&phone=573****

El autor del articulo de referencia dice lo siguiente:

"En la web de whatsapp sugieren este otro formato:

"https://api.whatsapp.com/send, Pero este formato tiene efectos algo diferentes en el proceso.

1. Si estamos en Android, primero te pedirá si quieres abrir el enlace con Whatsapp o Chrome. Añadiendo pues un paso extra.
2. En iOS directamente abre el enlace, es decir que primero va a la web de api.whatsapp.com y desde ahí llama a whatsapp, lo cual implica una redirección innecesaria.
3. Por otro lado en iOS, tras seleccionar el usuario, no abre directamente el chat con éste, sino que abre una vista de texto donde puedes introducir o modificar el mensaje y enviarlo. La vista es muy similar a la de los SMS con lo que la experiencia es confusa.

Por ello mi recomendación es evitarlo y llamar directamente a la app."

Referencia: http://www.elcssar.com/html/enlace-href-whatsapp?fbclid=IwAR0nLwweZQRAhRfcop5rHUadfbQWPY8isH6lTo3utRQX0A0uWB86wNHlP-k

Comment: Gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder, siempre es mejor dar mas detalles en las respuestas y no solo un enlace, ya que si eliminan el articulo a donde redirige el enlace, se pierde la respuesta que aportas. Revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: espero estén bien.
No está funcionando la URL desde la PC, desde el celular funciona correcto, pero dejo de funcionar con Whatsapp WEB o APP. Gracias por la información que puedan brindar.